# How to get the subdomain pointing to pm2 app with Nginx on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, nginx, hosts, subdomain

I have a hosted server that should serve both the domain `example.de` and `app.example.de`.

On `app.example.de` I would like to have my meteor/pm2 application being served.

I have created two configuration files for Nginx but I end up with the error `duplicate listen options for X.X.X.X:443`.

`default` configuration:

```
server {
    listen example.de:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.de;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.de; # managed by Certbot
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    listen example.de:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

`meteor` configuration

```
upstream app_nodejs {
    server app.example.de;
}

server {
    listen app.example.de:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot   
    server_name app.example.de;

    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
        rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
         include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?